# Unity Input.gyro.enabled throwing null pointer exception on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the gyroscope in Unity on an Andriod device that definitely has a gyroscope.  However, it keeps SIGSEV'ng with a null pointer dereference.

> From the tombstone: pid: 8732, tid: 8750, name: UnityMain  >>>
>   com.DefaultCompany.SIGV <<< signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR),
>   fault addr 0x0 Cause: null pointer dereference

I have the location permission set for the app, I can see it set in-app permissions on android.

Here's the code to enable the gyro. If I comment out Input.gyro.enabled, then the app runs.  If I don't it crashes.

```
private bool EnableGyro()
{
    if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
    {
        //gyros = Input.gyro; 
        //gyros.enabled = true;
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        /*
        cameraContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 90f, 0f);
        rot = new Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0);*/
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Oh and this is Android 8.1.

Comment: Have you triedi if (Input.isGyroAvailable)?

Comment: @zambari no but I just did and it says Input.isGyroAvailable is depreciated and I should use SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope :)